# SQL Query only returning every seven day increments rather than every day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a small scheduling app, where in the database I have scheduling blocks of two hour increments. The data structure looks like this:

```
schedule_blocks (
    block_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    day_of_week VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    start_time TIME NOT NULL,
    end_time TIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

Currently I have a schedule_block rows that has at least one block everyday of the week for one of the users. When I use this query I only seem to return back the current day, and seven day increments, not any other day of the week.

Here is the query I am using.

```
WITH RECURSIVE weekdays AS (
  SELECT generate_series(0, 60) AS offset
),
dates AS (
  SELECT
    CURRENT_DATE + (w.offset || ' days')::interval AS date,
    EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM CURRENT_DATE + (w.offset || ' days')::interval) AS day_of_week
  FROM weekdays w
  WHERE EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM CURRENT_DATE + (w.offset || ' days')::interval) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) -- Include only weekdays (Monday to Sunday)
),
schedule_blocks_with_dates AS (
  SELECT
    sb.*,
    d.date AS block_date
  FROM
    schedule_blocks sb
  JOIN dates d ON sb.day_of_week ILIKE to_char(d.date, 'Day')
  WHERE
    sb.is_available = TRUE
    AND d.date >= CURRENT_DATE
    AND d.date <= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '2 months'
)
SELECT
  block_id,
  user_id,
  block_date AS date,
  start_time,
  end_time
FROM
  schedule_blocks_with_dates
ORDER BY
  date;
```

Any guidance would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Please add example data and desired results ([mre]) as recommended here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)